# select string with specific character in regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Given the following text of example:

> Hello `$NAME$` how are you? You are visiting this `$LOGIN_PAGE$` page, please
>   fill the form and log in.

I want to select only the following "variable" `$LOGIN_PAGE$` without select even the `$NAME` character.

I made this regex trying to achieve the result but it select both of the string

```
(\$([A-Z\_])+\$)
```

Which part I'm missing in this regex?

Comment: why don't use `(\$LOGIN_PAGE\$)`?

Comment: `str_replace('$LOGIN_PAGE$', '/login', $haystack)` maybe?

Comment: prefer regex for more special strings

Comment: Sorry not clear if the string is constant then why are you using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would match only the the string which has only capital letters separated by underscore symbol where the start and  end of the string is `$`,

```
\$[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+\$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xJ2fP5/1)

Your PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$data = 'Hello $NAME$ how are you? You are visiting this $LOGIN_PAGE$ page, please fill the form and log in.' ;
$regex =  '~\$[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+\$~';
if (preg_match($regex, $data, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?> //=> $LOGIN_PAGE$
```